# how to get context properties in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I want to create a velocity template where I can get all context properties.
I tried just $context.keys but it returns me this result:

[text, VIEW_TOOLS_AVAILABLE, link, class, convert, esc, display, number, date, render, include, math, field, alternator, TOOLS_VERSION, GENERIC_TOOLS_AVAILABLE, sorter, context, loop, STRUTS_TOOLS_AVAILABLE, lists]

Here is the class I am using to create the engine and adding values in context.

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager;

public class VelocityTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.init();
    Template template = ve.getTemplate("Person.vtmpl");
    ToolManager velocityToolManager = new ToolManager();
    velocityToolManager.configure("tools.xml");
    VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext(velocityToolManager.createContext());
    ctx.put("FirstName", "John");
    ctx.put("LastName", "Doe");
    ctx.put("Age", 25);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(ctx, writer);
    System.out.println(writer);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to write a template which will get me the three values I add in my context.

Content of tools.xml

```
<tools> 
<toolbox scope="application">
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.AlternatorTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DisplayTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ComparisonDateTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ClassTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ConversionTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.FieldTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ListTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ResourceTool"/>
    <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.SortTool"/>
</toolbox>
</tools>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  What are you trying to output - the keys (FirstName, LastName and Age) or their values?  Also what is the content of tools.xml?

Comment: Yes, I want to print the keys only (firstName, lastName and age). The scope on tools.xml is set to application, updated question with contents